# Include non floating graphic in a theorem environment

Tags: graphics

In a mathematical text I use theorem environments, for example I have defined *example*. In some of these environments I‘d like to inlcude a graphic:

```
\begin{example}
  A nice example for this foo is the following:

  \includegrapcis{foo}.

  As you can see: \dots
\end{example}
```

Unfortunately that does not work very well. At first I am unable to add a caption, but that is not the main problem. The main problem is that the graphic‘s bottom and the text of my environment (“Example x.y”) are aligend at their bottom, ie. parts of the grapic are above the environment.

I tried some googling, ie. used the `placeins` package and `\FloatBarrier` (and put the `\includegraphics` in a `figure`) but without any good result.

How to include such a graphic in a not ugly way?

Comment: Could you show a screen shot of what you mean? This could be an issue with the image bounding box.

Comment: Please, make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to clarify the question. If the contents of environment `example` is set in vertical mode, then the image is in the *middle*. If it is set in horizontal mode, then the image can be moved via `\raisebox`, but a caption does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I understand the idea of a MWE, but since this question is answered, I do not see a reson to improve the question anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is enough to write something before `\includegraphics`, e.g. `mbox{}`. `\FloatBarrier`could do nothing since you do not have a float — which would make no sense in a theorem environment. I suggest you centre your image and use the `\captionof`  command  from the `caption` package. Here is a code with a figure inclusion that can be referenced:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[framed]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberbreak}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\mdseries\upshape}
\newframedtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}
\mbox{}%
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{zoom}
  \captionof{figure}{The example figure}\label{exfig1}
\end{center}
\end{example}
As can be seen in \cref{exfig1}, …

\end{document}
```

[image]